# Git Bash: remote error: You can't push to git://github.com/

Tags: git, git-push

Please, help me, how can I fix this error ?

```
$git push origin dev
fatal: remote error:
 You can't push to git://github.com//name_of_repo.git
 Use https:://github.com//name_of_repo.git
```

Comment: By using one of the repo URLs GitHub provides you (either via HTTPS or vie SSH) on the repo's page - not sure where you got the `git://` URL from in the first place.

Comment: btw, don't post screenshots of errors, post them as text instead

Comment: I used command -- $git clone git://github.com//name_of_repo.git

Comment: Where did you get this URL from? GitHub shows two options (HTTPS/SSH) to clone and neither of them use a git:// URL.

Comment: @ThiefMaster GitHub gives the problematic `git://` URL via the SSH "command line instructions" for merging pull requests. Weird ...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use an HTTPS or SSH URL. Instead of `git://github.com/user/repo.git` use one of these:

- `https://github.com/user/repo.git`
- `git@github.com:user/repo.git`

You can change it in your clone like this:

```
git remote set-url origin <THE-URL-HERE>
```

Comment: So, how can I replace `git://github.com/user/repo.git` to `https://github.com/user/repo.git` ?

Comment: added it to my answer

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error, and this worked for me, which I found here: https://coderwall.com/p/7begkw/fatal-remote-error-you-can-t-push-to-git

```
git remote rm origin 
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: Attempting to use `https` on Mac OS X 10.6.8 results in this error message: `error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version while accessing https://...............git`, so thank you for this solution

Comment: It also doesn't work when you have `git://`, you *have* to set it to `git@`

Answer (score 7):

The error message from github is quite misleading. It suggests to use https:// even when a user can much easier authenticate via ssh keys.
The (hopefully superior) alternative with ssh looks like this:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```